ROS2 workspace design with subpackages for larger projects
I am planning a package which contains multiple subpackages for a better organization.
ros2_workspace/
├── src/
│   ├── package_1/
│   │   ├── subpackage_1/
│   │   │   ├── src/
│   │   │   │   ├── subnode_1.cpp
│   │   │   │   └── subnode_2.cpp
│   │   │   ├── include/
│   │   │   │   └── subpackage_1/
│   │   │   │       └── subnode_1.hpp
│   │   │   ├── config/
│   │   │   │    └── subparameters.yaml
│   │   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── subpackage_2/
│   │   │   ├── src/
│   │   │   │   ├── subnode_3.cpp
│   │   │   │   └── subnode_4.cpp
│   │   │   ├── include/
│   │   │   │   └── subpackage_2/
│   │   │   │       └── subnode_3.hpp
│   │   │   ├── launch/
│   │   │   ├── config/
│   │   │   │   └── subparameters.yaml
│   │   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── launch/
│   │   │   ├── subpackage_1_launch.py
│   │   │   └── subpackage_2_launch.py
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── package.xml
│   └── package_2/
│       ├── src/
│       │   └── node_3.cpp
│       ├── include/
│       │   └── package_2/
│       │       └── node_3.hpp
│       ├── launch/
│       │   └── package_2_launch.py
│       ├── config/
│       │   └── parameters.yaml
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── package.xml
├── install/
├── build/
└── log/



In general, it works, and I'm aware I can't have nested packages so the package.xml exists only once per package. But what about the CMakeLists.txt?
With only CMakeLists.txt in the root directory of package_1 it compiles but is messy. When I split it into two for package_1 and a second one for subpackage_1 (ignore subpackage_2 for first) I get a lot of compiler errors.
For example:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/stamp.cmake:24 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:25 (stamp)
  /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_coreConfig.cmake:41 (include)
  /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:15 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/galactic/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmakeConfig.cmake:41 (include)

Is there a limitation for multiple CMakeLists.txt per package?

Might not be what you are searching for, but I have repos that contain different packages. I just clone them into my workspace's src directory.
So I have 'my_repo_for_object_detection' within src and this contains all ros packages that belong there.
